# symfony2 doctrine: many to many relation and SUBQUERY in doctrine

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two tables:
archive

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| author      | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| title       | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and collection

```
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| user_id    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| archive_id | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

these tables are linked with a ManyToMany relation, and of course I also have a user table. Collection table is generated running php app/console doctrine:schema:update and there are the entity definition:

USER ENTITY

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="My\ApplicationBundle\Entity\Archive", mappedBy="user")
**/
protected $archives;

/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="My\ApplicationBundle\Entity\Archive", inversedBy="users")
* @ORM\JoinTable(name="collection")
**/
private $collection;
```

ARCHIVE ENTITY

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="My\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="archives")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
**/
protected $user;

/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="My\UserBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="collection")
**/
private $users;
```

When I search for something in archive table, es:

```
select a.id, a.author, a.title, IF((select c.archive_id from collection c where c.archive_id = a.id and c.user_id = 1),1,0) as present from archive a;
```

I would also have a column indicating if a user (es: id: 1) has this archive in his collection, so my resultset should be something like

```
+----+---------------+--------------+---------+
| id | author        | title        | present |
+----+---------------+--------------+---------+
|  8 | test author 7 | test title 7 |       1 |
|  9 | test author 8 | title 8      |       0 |
| 10 | test 8 pdf    | title 9 pdf  |       1 |
+----+---------------+--------------+---------+
```

how can I translate the query above using doctrine DQB/DQL? many thanks

Comment: if not clear just ask

Comment: Add an entity ArchiveContact between your 2 entities with a property `present`, and query on this new entity.

Comment: Hi Veve, can you please provide an example? I updated my question with the entity definition. thanks

Comment: Look at my answer bellow, it contains an example ;)

Comment: I'm not able to adapt this example to my need. I'll use doctrine's createNativeQuery. thanks anyway for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Add an entity `ArchiveContact` between your 2 entities with a property `present`, and query on this new entity.

Example of such entity [from Doctrine documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html#use-case-3-join-table-with-metadata), with an entity `order` instead of `user`, an entity `product` instead of `archive`, and a property `offeredPrice` instead of `present`:

> In the classic order product shop example there is the concept of the
>   order item which contains references to order and product and
>   additional data such as the amount of products purchased and maybe
>   even the current price.

```
<?php
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/** @Entity */
class Order
{
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue */
    private $id;

    /** @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Customer") */
    private $customer;
    /** @OneToMany(targetEntity="OrderItem", mappedBy="order") */
    private $items;

    /** @Column(type="boolean") */
    private $payed = false;
    /** @Column(type="boolean") */
    private $shipped = false;
    /** @Column(type="datetime") */
    private $created;

    public function __construct(Customer $customer)
    {
        $this->customer = $customer;
        $this->items = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->created = new \DateTime("now");
    }
}

/** @Entity */
class Product
{
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue */
    private $id;

    /** @Column(type="string") */
    private $name;

    /** @Column(type="decimal") */
    private $currentPrice;

    public function getCurrentPrice()
    {
        return $this->currentPrice;
    }
}

/** @Entity */
class OrderItem
{
    /** @Id @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Order") */
    private $order;

    /** @Id @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product") */
    private $product;

    /** @Column(type="integer") */
    private $amount = 1;

    /** @Column(type="decimal") */
    private $offeredPrice;

    public function __construct(Order $order, Product $product, $amount = 1)
    {
        $this->order = $order;
        $this->product = $product;
        $this->offeredPrice = $product->getCurrentPrice();
    }
}
```